# Firebase: How to keep an Android user logged in using firebase otp authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase SimpleLogin to enable otp authentication. Creation of users and subsequent login is all working fine. However, whenever I leave the app completely all registration process start from registration process i want to stay logged in on dashboard.

this is flash activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASHTIMEOUT = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,register.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASHTIMEOUT);
    }
}
```

this is rgister activty

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText enternumber;
    Button getotpbutton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


        enternumber = findViewById(R.id.input_mobile_number);
        getotpbutton = findViewById(R.id.buttongetotp);


        final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar_sending_otp);

        getotpbutton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (!enternumber.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                if ((enternumber.getText().toString().trim()).length() == 10) {


                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    getotpbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                            "+91" + enternumber.getText().toString(),
                            60,
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                            register.this,
                            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                                @Override
                                public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    getotpbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    getotpbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    Toast.makeText(register.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String backendotp, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    getotpbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), otp.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("mobile", enternumber.getText().toString());
                                    intent.putExtra("backendotp",backendotp);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                    );


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "Please enter correct number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(register.this, "Enter Mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is otp activity

```
public class otp extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText inputnumber1, inputnumber2, inputnumber3, inputnumber4, inputnumber5, inputnumber6;

    String getotpbackend;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp);

        final Button verifybuttonclick = findViewById(R.id.buttongetotp);

        inputnumber1 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp1);
        inputnumber2 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp2);
        inputnumber3 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp3);
        inputnumber4 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp4);
        inputnumber5 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp5);
        inputnumber6 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp6);


        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textmobileshownumber);
        textView.setText(String.format(
                "+91-%s", getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile")
        ));

        getotpbackend = getIntent().getStringExtra("backendotp");

        final ProgressBar progressBarverifyotp = findViewById(R.id.progressbar_verify_otp);


        verifybuttonclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!inputnumber1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber4.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    String entercodeotp = inputnumber1.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber2.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber3.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber4.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber5.getText().toString() +
                            inputnumber6.getText().toString();

                    if (getotpbackend != null) {
                        progressBarverifyotp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        verifybuttonclick.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                                getotpbackend, entercodeotp
                        );
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                        progressBarverifyotp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        verifybuttonclick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                            startActivity(intent);

                                            

                                        }

                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(otp.this, "Enter the correct Otp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                    }

                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(otp.this, "Please check internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(otp.this, "otp verify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(otp.this, "please enter all number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        numberotpmove();



        TextView resendlabel = findViewById(R.id.textresendotp);

        resendlabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        "+91" + getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile"),
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        otp.this,
                        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

                                Toast.makeText(otp.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String newbackendotp, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {

                                getotpbackend = newbackendotp;
                                Toast.makeText(otp.this, "Otp sended Succussfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });

    }


    private void numberotpmove() {

        inputnumber1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber2.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber3.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber4.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber5.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    inputnumber6.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you signing out somewhere in your code? Since you are using Java, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) might help.

Comment: at dashboard there is a logout button